# Why is cv2.VideoCapture() returning sequences of duplicate frames on RPi Camera module (Using uv4l)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using a Raspberry PI & RPi Camera Module to capture video for a line following robot. I'm using Opencv functions & the uv4l driver. My problem is I'm getting frames returned from cv2.VideoCapture in sequences of 4 identical frames resulting in a low frame rate of about 5 fps. Has anyone else come across this issue?
Here is code used for capturing video:

```
 def open_camera(cam_id = 0):
     cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_id)
     cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
     cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
     cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);


     return cap

def get_frame(device):
     ret, img = device.read()
     if (ret == False): #failed to capture
         print >> sys.stderr, "Error capturing from vid dev"
         return None
     return img



def run(wh,sh,wh2,sh2): 
    find_colour(wh,sh,wh2,sh2)

    dev = open_camera(0)    

    while True:

        img = get_frame(dev) # get frame from cam
        if img is not None:# if possible to get imag
           #program code
        else: #if failed to cap
            #print 'failed to cap'
            controller.forward(128)#stop
            break


return()
```

Comment: Aren't you missing an indentation for the block following `While True:`?

Comment: @Antonio, Sorry Antonio, indentation was just an error in pasting the code in (corrected). This was not a problem in the actual program

Comment: What happens if you comment out the line `cap.set(...CV_CAP_PROP_FPS...)` and let it run at its natural framerate? In the c++ opencv, the get_frame() equivalent will return the most recent frame, if there is one, and block until a new one comes if your program is faster than the framerate. I would assume the same is true in python.

Comment: Mike you're a legend.. problem solved

Comment: Sorry Guys, This issue has not been resolved, still getting same problem

Comment: How did you decide exactly 4 frames are duplicated? Did you actually store frames and compare? Because there could be minor variations in frames at 30 fps.